# Having ClassCastException using endless adapter

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm having this classcastexception
I combine lazylist by Fedor and Endless by Commonware

i'm having this error

```
08-09 18:06:26.553: E/AndroidRuntime(314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 18:06:26.553: E/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.ClassCastException:com.example.endlesscustom.EndlessSample$CustomArrayAdapter
08-09 18:06:26.553: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at com.example.endlesscustom.EndlessSample$DemoAdapter.appendCachedData(EndlessSample.java:174)
08-09 18:06:26.553: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at com.commonsware.cwac.endless.EndlessAdapter$AppendTask.onPostExecute(EndlessAdapter.java:247)
```

It pointed out this error

```
ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> arrAdapterNew = ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>) getWrappedAdapter();
```

Here is my Code

```
public class EndlessSample extends ListActivity {

static int LIST_SIZE;
private int mLastOffset = 0;

static final int BATCH_SIZE = 3;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countriesSub = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maina);
    init();
    Log.i("country", String.valueOf(COUNTRIES.length));
    Log.i("mstrings", String.valueOf(mStrings.length));

}

private void init() {
    LIST_SIZE = COUNTRIES.length;
    for (int i = 0; i <= BATCH_SIZE; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("country", COUNTRIES[i]);
        map.put("pic", mStrings[i]);
        countriesSub.add(map);
    }
    setLastOffset(BATCH_SIZE);
    displayList(countriesSub);
}

private void setLastOffset(int i) {
    mLastOffset = i;
}

private int getLastOffset() {
    return mLastOffset;
}

private void displayList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countriesSub2) {
    setListAdapter(new DemoAdapter());
}

private class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist) {
        data = mylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) EndlessSample.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.word = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.throbber);
            holder.pecture = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imahe);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Log.i("data size", String.valueOf(data.size()));
        song = data.get(position);
        holder.word.setText(song.get("country"));
        // holder.word.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1) + ". "
        // + countriesSub.get(position));
         imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get("pic"), holder.pecture);
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView pecture;
        public TextView word;
    }
}

class DemoAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tempList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    DemoAdapter() {
        super(new CustomArrayAdapter(EndlessSample.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                countriesSub));

    }

    @Override
    protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        View child = row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        // child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        child = row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
        child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return (row);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
        tempList.clear();
        int lastOffset = getLastOffset();
        if (lastOffset < LIST_SIZE) {
            int limit = lastOffset + BATCH_SIZE;
            for (int i = (lastOffset + 1); (i <= limit && i < LIST_SIZE); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("country", COUNTRIES[i]);
                map.put("pic", mStrings[i]);
                tempList.add(map);
            }
            setLastOffset(limit);

            if (limit < LIST_SIZE) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void appendCachedData() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> arrAdapterNew = (ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>) getWrappedAdapter();
        int listLen = tempList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < listLen; i++) {
            arrAdapterNew.add(tempList.get(i));
        }
    }
}

static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Afghanistan", "Albania",
        "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla",
        "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia",
        "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain",
        "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin",
        "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
        "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil",
        "British Indian Ocean Territory", "British Virgin Islands",
        "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cote d'Ivoire",
        "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands",
        "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
        "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia",
        "Comoros", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia",
        "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
        "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti",
        "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt",
        "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia",
        "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji",
        "Finland", "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France",
        "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories",
        "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece",
        "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala",
        "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti",
        "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong",
        "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq",
        "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica" };

private String[] mStrings = {
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/681537837/SmallAvatarx150_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/63737974/2008-11-06_1637_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/612232882/nexusoneavatar_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/213722080/Bugdroid-phone_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/645523828/OT_icon_090918_android_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/681537837/SmallAvatarx150_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/63737974/2008-11-06_1637_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/612232882/nexusoneavatar_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/213722080/Bugdroid-phone_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/645523828/OT_icon_090918_android.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png" };
}
```

if anyone had encounter this error please help

thankyou so much

Comment: Instead of that, you can try [Never Ending List](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/)

Comment: thank you @SpK that is also a nice tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adapter you are putting into `EndlessAdapter` is a `CustomArrayAdapter`, not an `ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>`, which is why you get a `ClassCastException` when trying to cast the `CustomArrayAdapter` to `ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>` as part of your call to `getWrappedAdapter()`.

Comment: so i can only use ArrayAdapter<String>?? how to work with those images

Comment: @RoBin: You are using a `CustomArrayAdapter`. Please either *consistently* use `CustomArrayAdapter`, or get rid of `CustomArrayAdapter`. You cannot magically convert a `CustomArrayAdapter` into an `ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>` or a `ArrayAdapter<String>` or an `Integer` or a `Button`.